# ¿Cómo contar elementos de una columna sin tomar en cuanta los valores nulos en Laravel 6.0?

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando contar los elementos de una columna con Query Builder y no logro excluir los valores nulls del conteo, he intentado con este código pero no ha funcionado.

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as ttg, inc_padre'))
                 ->where('inc_padre', '<>', null)
                 ->groupBy('inc_padre ')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `whereNotNull`, como lo dice la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereNotNull('updated_at')
                    ->get();
```

En el caso de tu consulta sería así:

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as ttg, inc_padre'))
                 ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
                 ->groupBy('inc_padre')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: gracias por responder, con eso hago el conteo de los valores null.. pero no he podido contar los campos que tienen valores

Comment: Mi respuesta es a tu pregunta, en tu pregunta indicas como realizar el conteo sin tomar en cuenta los que tienen valores NULL.

Comment: quiero contar los valores que no son null.. que tienen algún valor, con whereNull hago el conteo de los valores Null, por eso coloque (sin tomar en cuenta los valores null)

Comment: No se si has leido o no mi respuesta, pero mi recomendación es usar `whereNotNull` no `whereNull` como indicas.

Comment: Si, con whereNotNull hago el conteo pero de cada uno de los elementos por separado, quisiera hacer un conteo general de todos los elementos que no son null, de igual forma gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Depende lo que necesites. Si necesitas tener si o sí los valores de inc_padre, entonces la respuesta de jolsalazar es totalmente válida.

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
        ->select('inc_padre', DB::raw('count(*) as ttg'))
        ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
        ->groupBy('inc_padre')
        ->get();
```

Ahora, si quieres contar sin tener en cuenta el campo "inc_padre", puedes usar count() al final de la sentencia y quedarte con el valor.

```
$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
        ->whereNotNull('inc_padre')
        ->count();
```

Comment: gracias amigo... si funciona el conteo... pero quiero un solo numero del conteo en general... con este método cuento cada uno de los elementos de la columna y me genera varios datos

Comment: quisiera poder contar todos los datos de la columna y los que se repitan contarlo como uno exceptuando los nulos

Comment: En otras palabras: Si hay algun registro de inc_padre, que solo se cuente 1 vez, evitando los nulos. ¿No?

Comment: ya pude resolver amigo, la solución que me estaban dando era la correcta... pero no tenia valores nulos en los registros si no valores vacíos, por eso no me hacia bien el conteo, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

No veo necesidad de usar constructor de consultas de dicha forma si pudiera quedar así

```
$datos = Incidencia::whereNotNull('inc_padre')->count();
```

Ahí

- Empleas el modelo
- Filtras los no nulos con `whereNotNull`
- Obtienes el conteo final

De esa forma mantienes más simple la consulta, dado que tú `count` es un tanto genérico por eso considero este método concatenado al final debería bastar

Comment: me esta contando todas las lineas amigo.. incluyendo los valores nulos